# need BPEL tutorials

Tags: web-services, bpel

I need BPEL tutorial to show me how to write BPEL manually, I want to learn how to use structure activities, and I want to know how can I make predicate expression .
 I want to know how to compare 2 values one of them is boolean 
  when I make like this, an exception occur that '==' is wrong expression

```
 $IsItemExistOut.itemResoponse == true
```

Please can some one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to work with Oracle SOA suite which has a BPEL component.  The OTN on Oracle has an intro to BPEL that may get you started.  See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/matjaz-bpel1-090575.html.  They obviously are Oracle tech specific.

If you are an OSS guy then ActiveBpel may be your speed.  Take a look at their resources: http://www.activebpel.org/samples/samples-2/BPEL_Samples/doc/index.html#introduction.  Install the samples and then take them apart.  See how they work and what they are doing.

Comment: I fix the proplen:) , I should have made like this <if name="CreditCardCheck"> <condition>$IsItemExistOut.itemResoponse </condition> </if> without == true ,becouse it's a boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

This BPEL tutorial will be helpful to you. It has covered most of the parts you have requested. 
[Writing a simple WS-BPEL process for WSO2 BPS and Apache ODE](http://wso2.org/library/articles/writing-simple-ws-bpel-process-wso2-bps-apache-ode) 

This article will be helpful if you trying to write a BPEL process using an IDE. [Developing WS-BPEL Processes using WSO2 Carbon Studio](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2011/04/using-carbon-studio-model-wsbpel-process-using-bpel-editor)